# Android test storage health: get storage and Ram health

Tags: android, storage, ram

I want to develop an android application to test storage and memory health

- Get total disk sectors
- Get **bad** sector
- Get Memory health

Can android provide this kind of information?

Comment: There are no "disk sectors" in flash memory, and I am not aware of any major Android device that uses magnetic media (e.g., hard drives) that might have disk sectors. And it is unclear what you mean by "Ram health".

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I mean by ram :Memory.
Can i at least check health disk or memory.